# codeigniter access data array in ajax success function

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, codeigniter

my problem is that i can't access the array returned from controller to ajax success function.

here my controller code:

```
function get_slot()
{
    $fac_id = 1;
    $date = $this->input->post('date');

    $this->load->model('booking_model');
    $result = $this->booking_model->get_slot_availablity($date, $fac_id );  
    $data['booking'] = $result['row'];

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

my ajax function:

```
 $.ajax({
          type : "Post",
           url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/index/get_slot",
          data : "date="+date,
      dataType : 'json',
       success : function(result)
                {
                    $.each(result, function(index, val) {
                        alert(val.slot_id); 
                    });
                }
       });
```

my model function:

```
public function get_slot_availablity($date, $fac_id){

    $q = $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('booking')
    ->where('f_id', $fac_id)
    ->where('date', $date);

    $res['row'] = $q->get()->result();

    return $res;
}
```

the function displays **undefined**

Comment: Check browser console, what is you are getting from server?

Comment: there is no need to header() first alert(result); in your success block then start parse your json data

Comment: i already delete header(), and i add dataType json..but still get undefined @RakeshSharma

Comment: Please list this `$this->booking_model->get_slot_availablity()` function's code as well.

Comment: i already edit my question @Mysteryos

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser console network tab to see exactly what is returned and status of request.

Comment: status= ok, response = {"booking":[{"id":"1","date":"2015-01-22","slot_id":"2","f_id":"1"}]} @charlietfl

Comment: So the booking element has your db results in an array. Obviously, since you did `json_encode($data['booking'])`

Comment: I don't understand why you create needless php arrays in model and in `get_slot`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your latest comment, your JS code should be as follows:

```
$.ajax({
      type : "Post",
       url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/index/get_slot",
      data : "date="+date,
  dataType : 'json',
   success : function(result)
            {
                $.each(result.booking, function(index, val) {
                    alert(val.slot_id); 
                });
            }
   });
```

Comment: please could you explain more about your latest comment above?

Comment: You are echoing a json encoded `$data` variable, whereby the `$data['booking']` contains your DB result. Translating the array to JSON, `booking` becomes an attribute of your `result` object, hence the `result.booking`.

Comment: i got it, i guess its better to return the array from model directly to result object instead of using multiple objects. thank you @Mysteryos

Comment: Indeed. Also, i would recommend you step away from CodeIgniter's active record. It may be good for simple stuff, but has no alternative for complex mySQL queries. Go with raw mySQL and bring uniformity to your codebase.

Comment: thank you @Mysteryos for the hints and advices, appreciate it :)